# Is there a way to save screenshots to custom location using gnome-screenshot?

Tags: command-line, gnome-screenshot

I **DO NOT** want to change the default location for screenshots, nor use interface. I want to use `gnome-screenshot` in some specific cases to save to a different folder.

I know about the `-f` or `--file` option to save to a specific file, but is there a way to save to a directory/folder?

I'm on Ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-f` option to specify the directory too. For example

```
gnome-screenshot -f ~/MyFolder/FileName.png
```

To avoid overwriting you may add date-time to the file name, for example like this:

```
gnome-screenshot -f ~/MyFolder/Screenshot\ from\ $(date "+%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S").png
```

Answer (score 1):

Take your screenshot, select where to save from the pull down menu - "Save in folder"

[image]

From the command line just specify a location

```
bodhi@daemon:~$gnome-screenshot -f /home/bodhi/Pictures/testing.123.jpeg

bodhi@daemon:~$ls /home/bodhi/Pictures/ | grep test 
testing.123.jpeg
```

Comment: I need to use command line, with no interfaces. I edited my post to specify this.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, but if you just want to set a directory and not the filename manually, you can do:

```
HOME=/path/to/directory gnome-screenshot
```

`gnome-screenshot` saves in the `~/Pictures` folder by default, since that is what `XDG_PICTURES_DIR` is usually set to in [`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/user-dirs.dirs`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_user_directories) (`"$HOME/Pictures"`). But if that directory doesn't exist, or `XDG_PICTURES_DIR` isn't defined, it dumps the screenshot in `$HOME`. And since:

- `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is taken to be `$HOME/.config` if not explicitly set,
- and there's unlikely to be a `.config/user-dirs.dir` file in `/path/to/directory`

this command causes gnome-screenshot to dump the screenshot in `/path/to/directory`.

Or, less hacky but more complicated, create a directory somewhere (say `/path/to/another/dir`), with a `user-dirs.dir` file in it containing:

```
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="/path/to/dir"
```

Then you can do:

```
XDG_CONFIG_DIR=/path/to/another/dir gnome-screenshot
```

and again the screenshot will end up in `/path/to/dir`.