# How can I auto-generate a filename for gnome-screenshot?

Tags: command-line, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

I would like to use the following command:

```
$ gnome-screenshot -caf=<file name>
```

How can I pass something auto-generated like `Screenshot from 2017-12-07 20-22-56.png` for `<file name>`?

Comment: I want to copy to clipboard and store as file at the same time.

Comment: `gnome-screenshot` already auto-generates filenames. Seems weird to do your own auto-generation on top of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `date` command for the task of including the actual date and time into the filename. Let's see what we can find in the [`date` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/date):

> OPERANDS
>
> ```
>    The following operands shall be supported:
>
>    +format   When the format is specified, each conversion specifier shall
>              be replaced in  the  standard  output  by  its  corresponding
>              value.  All  other  characters  shall be copied to the output
>              without change. The output shall always be terminated with  a
>              <newline>.
> ```
>
> Conversion Specifications
>                    %a      Locale's abbreviated weekday name.
>
> ```
>              %A      Locale's full weekday name.
>
>              %b      Locale's abbreviated month name.
>
>              %B      Locale's full month name.
>
>              %c      Locale's appropriate date and time representation.
>
>              %C      Century  (a  year  divided by 100 and truncated to an
>                      integer) as a decimal number [00,99].
>
>              %d      Day of the month as a decimal number [01,31].
>
>              %D      Date in the format mm/dd/yy.
>
>              %e      Day of the month as a decimal number [1,31] in a two-
>                      digit field with leading <space> character fill.
>
>              %h      A synonym for %b.
>
>              %H      Hour (24-hour clock) as a decimal number [00,23].
>
>              %I      Hour (12-hour clock) as a decimal number [01,12].
>
>              %j      Day of the year as a decimal number [001,366].
>
>              %m      Month as a decimal number [01,12].
>
>              %M      Minute as a decimal number [00,59].
>
>              %n      A <newline>.
>
>              %p      Locale's equivalent of either AM or PM.
>
>              %r      12-hour  clock time [01,12] using the AM/PM notation;
>                      in the POSIX locale,  this  shall  be  equivalent  to
>                      %I:%M:%S %p.
>
>              %S      Seconds as a decimal number [00,60].
>
>              %t      A <tab>.
>
>              %T      24-hour clock time [00,23] in the format HH:MM:SS.
>
>              %u      Weekday as a decimal number [1,7] (1=Monday).
>
>              %U      Week  of  the  year  (Sunday  as the first day of the
>                      week) as a decimal number [00,53]. All days in a  new
>                      year  preceding  the first Sunday shall be considered
>                      to be in week 0.
>
>              %V      Week of the year (Monday as  the  first  day  of  the
>                      week)  as  a  decimal  number  [01,53].  If  the week
>                      containing January 1 has four or more days in the new
>                      year,  then it shall be considered week 1; otherwise,
>                      it shall be the last week of the previous  year,  and
>                      the next week shall be week 1.
>
>              %w      Weekday as a decimal number [0,6] (0=Sunday).
>
>              %W      Week  of  the  year  (Monday  as the first day of the
>                      week) as a decimal number [00,53]. All days in a  new
>                      year  preceding  the first Monday shall be considered
>                      to be in week 0.
>
>              %x      Locale's appropriate date representation.
>
>              %X      Locale's appropriate time representation.
>
>              %y      Year within century [00,99].
>
>              %Y      Year with century as a decimal number.
>
>              %Z      Timezone name, or no characters  if  no  timezone  is
>                      determinable.
>
>              %%      A <percent-sign> character.
>
>              See  the  Base  Definitions  volume  of POSIX.1‐2008, Section
>              7.3.5, LC_TIME for the conversion  specifier  values  in  the
>              POSIX locale.
> ```

Since `date` can not have spaces formatted into its output you would have to use two date commands as shown below, first for the date you can use `+\%Y.\%m.\%d` as a parameter which will result in a date format like `2017.12.07` and for the time you can use `+\%H:\%M:\%S` which will result in a format like `20:37:18`.

The clipboard option (`-c`) does not work together with the save as filename option (`-f`) of `gnome-screenshot`, so you have to choose either one. This command will do it (just edit the `c` back in if you need the clipboard, but then let the `f` and the filename out, both wont work together):

```
gnome-screenshot -af "Screenshot from $(date +\%Y.\%m.\%d) $(date +\%H:\%M:\%S).png"
```

It generates a file name like the following (just with the actual date and time you call this command at):

```
Screenshot from 2017.12.07 20:37:18.png
```

This will however store the file inside the directory you are currently in, to add a path like `~/Pictures` you need to provide a full path since `~` does not get expanded inside the quotes. The following would save the files for example in your pictures folder:

```
gnome-screenshot -af "/home/$USER/Pictures/Screenshot from $(date +\%Y.\%m.\%d) $(date +\%H:\%M:\%S).png"
```

Or you get rid of the quotes which then would mean you can use the tilde (`~`) but then you have to escape all spaces in the name:

```
gnome-screenshot -af ~/Pictures/Screenshot\ from\ $(date +\%Y.\%m.\%d)\ $(date +\%H:\%M:\%S).png
```

See [`man date`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/date) and [`man gnome-screenshot`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/gnome-screenshot) as well as [Bash reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) for further details.

Comment: Nice! This stores in `~`. Can we put it in `~/Pictures`?

Comment: @orschiro Yes, you can [add path too](https://askubuntu.com/a/977091/480481), but it *won't* copy to clipboard simultaneously.

Comment: For some reasons, this one segfaults. `orschiro@x230 ~ $ gnome-screenshot -af "~/Pictures/Screenshot from $(date +\%Y.\%m.\%d) $(date +\%H:\%M:\%S).png"
** Message: Unable to select area using GNOME Shell's builtin screenshot interface, resorting to fallback X11.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Comment: @orschiro Try `gnome-screenshot -af ~/Pictures/Screenshot\ from\ $(date +\%Y.\%m.\%d)\ $(date +\%H:\%M:\%S).png`.

Comment: This is great! It just seems that you cannot use `-cf` at the same time. Can you confirm?

Comment: Well it gives no output for me if I do `-cf`how am I supposed to paste that? For sure I get no segmentation fault (17.10 Vanilla Gnome on Xorg here). And well I can paste it in Gimp but then the whole filename is lost.

Comment: @orschiro `-c`: "Send the grab directly to the clipboard"; `-f`: "Save screenshot directly to this file", so it seems they don't work together.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I filed [Bug 791373 – Ability to use -c and -f together?](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=791373)

Comment: Any chance we can also add the window name or title we are taking a screenshot from?

Comment: to be noted that adding this command as a keyboard shortcut doesn't work. 'date' does not get interpreted correctly.

Comment: This can be solved by creating a .sh file containing the full command, and set it as executable. Then have the keyb shortcut point to it.